# VBA: Array of Variable Names

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a macro that copies a row(s) from one "master" worksheet up to several other worksheets based on a set of rules, but not every row will be copied to every worksheet. So I have a set of variables which serve as "counters" for each row on the different worksheets so that I can keep track of the current row and not overwrite any rows on any given worksheet. This leads to a lot of ugly code similar to the following.

```
.Rows(material.Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("QM").Range("A" & QMCounter)
```

I would like to make this into a single sub that I can call where I pass it the row number from the master worksheet, the intended worksheet and then the counter variable for the worksheet.

What I would like to do is create an array of the different counter variable names so that I could do something similar to the following

```
For i = 0 to Ubound(VarNameArray)

    Counter = VarNameArray(i)        

    Call CopyRow(Material, DestWorksheet, Counter)

Next i
```

My problem is translating the string value of the variable name into the actual variable name so that `VarNameArray(i)` can become not the string "QMCounter" but the variable `QMCounter`. Since not every row from the "master" worksheet will be copied to every other worksheet, I need to be able to control the value of each counter variable independently. Is this possible with VBA?

**Edit:** This aim of this spreadsheet is to look at specific cell values in rows on the "master" sheet and then based on those values, copies that row to a combination of 10 "subordinate" worksheets. So, for example, Row 1 of the "master" sheet may be copied only to subordinate sheet 9, but Row 2 of the master sheet may be copied to subordinate sheets 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9 and 10. Then Row 3 may be copied to a different set of subordinate sheets. It all depends on values of specific cells, which I do not know in advance.

I have counter variables for each of the 10 subordinate sheets to keep track of the current row and make sure that I do not simply keep copying everything to the first row on that sheet. Call them Sheet1 through 10 and Counter1 through 10, Sheet1 and Counter1 being linked on through 10. So if I copy a row from the master sheet to Sheet1, and only if I copy from the master sheet to Sheet1, I increment Counter1. However, as I have already stated, the specific subordinate sheets a row is copied to is determined at run time based on values of specific cells filled in by the users.

So I want to take a highly repetitive bit of code like

```
.Rows(material.Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Counter1)
.Rows(material.Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Counter3)
.Rows(material.Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Counter4)
```

where 99% of the code is the same, with something cleaner and more generic.

Comment: What you want to do can't be done the way you want to do it. I suggest that you tell us more about your actual goal and stop focusing on your perceived problem.

Comment: @RubberDuck - The goal is to refactor my code. Take the ugly and highly repetitive (but functional) code like the first code snippet and replace it with (ideally) something like the loop code where I have a single sub that I pass the pertinent info to (master row, destination sheet and row on the destination sheet).

Comment: The short answer is: this can't be done in VBA. Now, it seems like you at least understand the concept of For/Next looping, I think the problem is simply the way you're trying to implement it, but without seeing more of your code, and a better example of the problem (and desired solution --- please revise your OP to include these details!) it's going to be difficult to assist.

Comment: @Aerogems there is a SE site dedicated to that. Please bring your fully functioning code over to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). All of it please. We can help you out over there, but please be aware that the rules are a little different on that site. Please read the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting a question there.

Comment: @DavidZemens - The "problem" is mostly that I can't figure out an effective way to replace code that is about 99% the same with a single generic version where I can just change the variables. I have a couple dozen lines like the first code snippet where the only thing that changes is the destination sheet and the counter variable. The counter var is the sticking point since I'm not always copying to the same set of worksheets.

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: Other methods of doing what I think you're doing:  1.  apply filter to your master for the rules for each worksheet; then copy/paste the filtered cells in a single step;  2.  Use collections for each worksheet; then write the collections to an array; then array-->worksheet as a single step; 3.  Compute last row with each write (this would probably be the slowest method).

Comment: @RubberDuck and Mat's Mug - Not only is this just one part of a much larger set of code, but it contains a lot of info which would be considered confidential to my employer. Removing it would break the code as a whole.

Comment: @Aerogems thanks for respecting both the CR community and your employer. Keep in mind that we're there. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for an array of variable names when you can just use an array directly...

```
Dim Counters
Counters = Array(1,2,3,4,5)

For i = LBound(Counters) to Ubound(Counters)

    CopyRow Material, DestWorksheet, Counters(i)

Next i
```

EDIT: if you're just appending new rows below any existing ones:

```
.Rows(material.Row).Copy _
   Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).offset(1,0)
```

Works as long as there's always a value in ColA for any copied row.

Comment: Except that I'm not always using the same counters. I have 10 subordinate worksheets to my one master sheet, but sometimes row 5 on the master sheet may only be copied to sheets 2, 6 and 9, but then row 6 gets copied to sheets 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 10. This is all determined by the values of specific cells. So I need to make sure that the counters associated with the specific worksheets are updated, not just any random counter.

Comment: Then use something like a dictionary where you can do `dictRows("Sheet1")=10` and `dictRows("Sheet1")=dictRows("Sheet1")+1`  or if you're just appending rows on the end of a dataset then use `End(xlUp)` and don't track the row numbers at all.

Comment: The example from the edit was enough to get me started and I was able to adapt it. It does come with the added bug where if I run the macro a second time without clearing the values from the subordinate sheets, it gives me duplicate values, but I'll just implement a sub to clear the other sheets every time the main code is run. I probably should have already done that anyway.